# Lista ordenada de nombres (Bash)

Tags: bash

Estoy intentando utilizar un solo comando en Bash que me permita ver los contenidos de un archivo de texto en formato de lista y en orden alfabético.

El archivo de texto contiene apellidos de varias personas pero aparecen separados por espacios, y no por líneas. Además, tampoco están ordenados alfabéticamente.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo del archivo  y de cómo quieres verlo?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes reemplazar los espacios con saltos de linea con **tr** y luego ordenarlos con el comando **sort**. En una sola linea:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < nombres.txt | sort
```

Usando **cat**

```
cat nombres.txt | tr ' ' '\n' | sort
```

Comment: Pero eso implicaría tener que modificar el archivo original (para incluir los saltos de línea). ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer lo mismo sin tener que modificarlo?

Comment: Si utilizas el ejemplo no estarias modificando el archivo original, solo mostrando.

Comment: El ejemplo que te pone @cardeol coje la salida del archivo que muestra x pantalla. Como bien te indica, eso afecta a la salida x pantalla, no al contenido del archivo.